# How to prove the following sygyzy functor is fully faithful?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be a noetherian semiperfect ring. Let $\underline{\text{mod}} \Lambda := (\text{mod} \Lambda)/[ \Lambda ] $, i.e. $\Lambda$-modules without projective direct summand and $\underline{\text{Hom}}_{\Lambda}(X,Y)$ the set of morphisms in $\underline{\text{mod}} \Lambda$. $\Omega: \underline{\text{mod}} \Lambda \rightarrow \underline{\text{mod}} \Lambda$ is the syzygy functor.

We set  $\mathcal{X}_1= \{ M \in \text{mod} \Lambda  \mid \text{Ext}_{\Lambda}^1(M, \Lambda) =0 \}$. Then how to check that $\Omega: \underline{\text{Hom}}_{\Lambda}(X,Y) \rightarrow \underline{\text{Hom}}_{\Lambda}(\Omega X, \Omega Y) $ is bijective for any $X \in \mathcal{X}_1$ and $Y \in \text{mod} \Lambda$? (If $\Lambda$ is a finite dimensional selfinjective algebra, we know $\Omega: \underline{\text{mod}} A \rightarrow \underline{\text{mod}} A $ is an equivalence, so the above is clearly bijective, but how to  prove the general case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is claimed in the proof of Proposition 1.1.1(2) of the paper [I] without an explicit proof. Here is a direct proof.

Let's denote the projective cover of $X$ and $Y$ by $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

**Surjectivity**: By applying the functor $\text{Hom}(-, Q)$ to the short exact sequence $0\to\Omega X\to P\to X\to 0$, and using the fact that $\text{Ext}^1(X, \Lambda)=0$, we may show that every map $\Omega X\to Q$ factors through $\Omega X\to P$, and thus yields a map $P\to Q$. By universal property of cokernels, this furthermore induces a map $X\to Y$, which is exactly the one we are looking for.

**Injectivity**: This part is a bit more complicated. We refer to the diagram below for notations.

[image: Notations]

We start with the upper and lower short exact sequences, with maps $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ such that the two squares commute. We assume that $\alpha$ factors through a projective module $F$, and we are to show that $\gamma$ also factors through projectives.

Let the red parallelogram be the pushout of $a$ and $\varepsilon$, and we obtain the middle exact sequence. $\kappa$ is then induced via universal property of pushouts, making the coloured part of the diagram commutes.

Since $\text{Ext}^1(X, \Lambda)=0$, the middle exact sequence splits via $j$ and $q$. We claim that $\gamma=d\kappa j$.

By appending a surjection $b$ to the start, it suffices to show $\gamma b=d\kappa j b$. Also since $b=p\eta$, it suffices to show $\gamma b=d\kappa j p \eta$. Now notice that $0=d\kappa (iq)=d\kappa(1-jp)=d\kappa -d\kappa jp$. We have $d\kappa j p \eta=d\kappa\eta=d\beta=\gamma b$. It yields that $\gamma$ factors through $Q$, which is projective.

[I] *Iyama, Osamu*, [**Higher-dimensional Auslander-Reiten theory on maximal orthogonal subcategories.**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2006.06.002), Adv. Math. 210, No. 1, 22-50 (2007). [ZBL1115.16005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1115.16005).